# Python Imaging Library- Merging one type of pixel into another image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Basically, I have two images. One is comprised of white and black pixels, the black pixels making up a word, and the other image that I'm trying to paste the black pixels on top of. I've pasted the code below, however I'm aware that there's an issue with the "if pixels [x,y] == (0, 0, 0):' being a tuple and not an indice, however I'm uncertain of how to get it to look for black pixels with other means.

So essentially I need to find, and remember the positions of, the black pixels so that I can paste them onto the first image. Any help is very much appreciated!

```
image_one = Image.open (image_one)
image_two = Image.open (image_two)

pixels = list(image_two.getdata())

for y in xrange(image_two.size[1]):
    for x in xrange(image_two.size[0]):
        if pixels[x,y] == (0, 0, 0):
            pixels = black_pixels
            black_pixels.append()

image = Image.open (image_one);

image_one.putdata(pixels)

image.save(image_one+ "_X.bmp")

del image_one, image_two;
```

Comment: Be careful with how you've used the variable name `image_one` for two different things.  In the first line, it seems to be a string (as the argument to `open`), but then you assign a `PIL.Image` object to it.   Next you try to open it again and assign it to `image`, but it's already opened at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. I am not too familiar with the PIL class, but instead of calling the getdata method, let's use getpixel directly on the image object, and directly set the results into the output image.  That eliminates the need to store the set of pixels to overwrite.  However, there may be cases beyond what you've listed here where such an approach would be necessary.  I created a random image and then set various pixels to black.  For this test I used a different condition - if the R channel of the image is greater than 50.  You can comment that out and use the other test, which tests for tuple (R,G,B) == (0,0,0) which will work fine.

```
imagea = PIL.Image.open('temp.png')
imageb = PIL.Image.open('temp.png')

for y in xrange(imagea.size[1]):
  for x in xrange(imagea.size[0]):
    currentPixel = imagea.getpixel((x,y))

    if currentPixel[0] >  50:
    #if currentPixel ==(0,0,0):
      #this is a black pixel, you can directly modify image 2 now
      imageb.putpixel((x,y),(0,0,0))

imageb.save('outputfile.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to do this is just to multiply the two images together.  Any pixel that's black in the binary image will be black in the result (multiply by zero) and any pixel that's white in the binary image will be unchanged from the other image in the result (multiply by one).

PIL can do this,

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

image_one = Image.open("image_one.bmp")
image_two = Image.open("image_two.bmp")

out = ImageChops.multiply(image_one, image_two)
out.save("output.bmp")
```